# Can python compare user input with variables in program?

Tags: python, calculator

This is my first post here, hope it is easily readable and also my answer is asked! (:

First of all, to put you a bit into perspective, I wanted to create an efficiency calculator for the brand new game No Man's Sky. The economy in that game is pretty much the same as in real life. You can sell items at a much higher price than the components needed to create it. E.g: You can sell a rock for 5000€ or 30 rock parts for 30€ each. If you craft the rock with the rock parts your profit will be 5000-900, right? (:

Here is the [code](http://pastebin.com/Qitb7hgp).

What I want it to do is the following. User enters a product, the program compares the price of the product if sold and the price of the components to craft the product and shows you the profit doing so.

I have the following questions about it:

1. Is there a better way to save the data to use it after? (lines 1-16)
2. Is there any way to compare all variables I will create (line 18) or do I have to create an if loop for every product (lines 22-24). What I mean is something like

   ```
   profit = products[input] - input_recipe
   print profit
   ```

Since I want to check a lot of recipes, it would be a pain in the ass if there's a better for to do it.

Comment: If you want to ask us about some code, post the relevant code in the question. Also it's probably better to ask about one thing at a time, as succinctly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your first question, another way would be to use **json** format to store your data and not to use three separate dictionaries, I mean something like:

```
data = {"elements":{"Th":20.6,"Pu":41.3},"alloys":{"Aronium":1546.9,"Herox":2877.5},"Products":{"Antimatter":5232,"Warp Cell":46750}}
```

You could parse for example "Th" price by writing:

```
th_price = data['elements']['Th']
```

As for your second question you could create a fourth dictionary that would contain the prices of all the possible recipes which of course you have predefined - just not to compute them every time you need them and to have them available for fast parsing. So you would write something like:

```
profit = products[input] - input_recipe[input]
print profit
```

where input_recipe would be your fourth dictionary with the recipe prices.

Comment: thanks a lot, I implemented it with your help and this is what I got: http://pastebin.com/xLkAxAun I think it turned out pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

How you save the data and access it will really depend on how you want to handle your calculator.  I would say the best way to handle this would be if there were an excel file or JSON file or something of the sort that is all inclusive of all materials and items of the game (you may have to be the one to make this or someone else may already have).  In the event you have to put the list together yourself, it could be a long process and very annoying, so try to find a list somewhere you can download then open the file and parse the data as needed.  You could put all the data in the code itself but that doesn't allow you to write code against the data with say a different language if you so desired.

As far as loops are concerned, I'm not sure what you mean by that?  You have dictionaries for your data so there's no need to loop over every value right?  Now if you are referring to taking in multiple user inputs, a loop wouldn't be a bad idea for command line:

```
continue_calculations = 'y'
while continue_calculations != 'n':
     # Do your logic here.
     continue_calculations = raw_input('Would you like to continue(y/n)?')
```

Of course if you are making a calculator you could look into GUI development, or web development if you want to make it into a site. PyQT is a handy little module to work in and there are some good tutorials for that: https://pythonprogramming.net/basic-gui-pyqt-tutorial/

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the info, I already solved it. I will try GUI development, I'm not interested in site development yet, but would be nice to learn how to develop my own GUI!